# Opening named shared memory in windows kernel

Tags: c++, c, windows, kernel, windows-kernel

I'm trying to pass off two addresses from a user mode program to my kernel mode driver via shared memory. I couldn't find any resources online about opening named mapped memory in kernel so I figured I could just use ZwOpenFile with the name I used in the user mode program. The issue is that the driver is logging "Could not load shmem" so I don't know how to open it correctly.

User mode code:

```
#define BUF_SIZE 256
TCHAR szName[] = TEXT("Global\\MyFileMappingObject");
TCHAR szMsg[] = TEXT("0x0\n0x1");

int main() {
    HANDLE hMapFile;
    LPCTSTR pBuf;

    hMapFile = CreateFileMapping(
        INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE,    // use paging file
        NULL,                    // default security
        PAGE_READWRITE,          // read/write access
        0,                       // maximum object size (high-order DWORD)
        BUF_SIZE,                // maximum object size (low-order DWORD)
        szName);                 // name of mapping object

    if (hMapFile == NULL)
    {
        _tprintf(TEXT("Could not create file mapping object (%d).\n"),
            GetLastError());
        return 1;
    }
    pBuf = (LPTSTR)MapViewOfFile(hMapFile,   // handle to map object
        FILE_MAP_ALL_ACCESS, // read/write permission
        0,
        0,
        BUF_SIZE);

    if (pBuf == NULL)
    {
        _tprintf(TEXT("Could not map view of file (%d).\n"),
            GetLastError());

        CloseHandle(hMapFile);

        return 1;
    }


    CopyMemory((PVOID)pBuf, szMsg, (_tcslen(szMsg) * sizeof(TCHAR)));
    Pause(); // I run the kernel driver when code is here, shmem is still mapped

    UnmapViewOfFile(pBuf);

    CloseHandle(hMapFile);
```

Kernel driver code:

```
HANDLE shmem;
OBJECT_ATTRIBUTES attrs;
UNICODE_STRING     uniName;
OBJECT_ATTRIBUTES  objAttr;
IO_STATUS_BLOCK    ioStatusBlock;

RtlInitUnicodeString(&uniName, L"Global\\MyFileMappingObject");

InitializeObjectAttributes(&attrs, &uniName, OBJ_CASE_INSENSITIVE, NULL, NULL);
if (!NT_SUCCESS(ZwOpenFile(&shmem, READ_CONTROL, &attrs, &ioStatusBlock, FILE_SHARE_READ, FILE_NON_DIRECTORY_FILE))) {
    log("Could not load shmem");
}
else {
    log("shmem loaded successfully");
    ZwClose(shmem);
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: In the kernel memory mapped files are called sections, take a look at ZwOpenSection.

Comment: yes, `ZwOpenSection` and path must be `\\BaseNamedObjects\\MyFileMappingObject`

Comment: About first solution, do you check  `hMapFile` when you call `CreateFileMapping` ? i remember i had a problem with `Global` prefix in `"Global\\MyFileMappingObject"` (replaced by `Local`)

Comment: @RbMm How come it returns STATUS_INVALID_PARAMETER whenever I call ZwMapViewOfSection like this? `KeParams params;
  SIZE_T ViewSize = 0;
  PVOID vParams = &params;
  NTSTATUS status = ZwMapViewOfSection(shmem, ZwCurrentProcess(), &vParams, 0, 0, NULL, &ViewSize, ViewUnmap, MEM_RESERVE, PAGE_READWRITE);`

Comment: at first `vParams = &params` of course wrong. must be `vParams = 0` at second use 0 instead `MEM_RESERVE` and finally i strong doubt that you got `STATUS_INVALID_PARAMETER` but not `STATUS_INVALID_PARAMETER_3`

Comment: Thanks that fixed it, and yea it was returning 0xC000000D which is STATUS_INVALID_PARAMETER

Comment: very unusual if `ZwMapViewOfSection` return `STATUS_INVALID_PARAMETER`. it return `STATUS_INVALID_PARAMETER_N`

Comment: Yea and after mapping this happens: `KeParams* params = (KeParams*)vParams; log("KeParams Recieved - (%i, %i)", params->PID, params->SetTargetProcess_Address);` The PID is 255 and the SetTargetProcess_Address is 0

Answer (score 0):

Solved, use ZwOpenSection and the path starts with \\BaseNamedObjects\\

```
HANDLE shmem;
OBJECT_ATTRIBUTES attrs;
UNICODE_STRING     uniName;

RtlInitUnicodeString(&uniName, L"\\BaseNamedObjects\\MyFileMappingObject");
InitializeObjectAttributes(&attrs, &uniName, OBJ_CASE_INSENSITIVE, NULL, NULL);
if (!NT_SUCCESS(ZwOpenSection(&shmem, FILE_SHARE_READ, &attrs))) {
    log("Could not load shmem");
}
else {
    log("shmem loaded successfully");
    ZwClose(shmem);
}
```

Comment: `FILE_SHARE_READ` have nothing common to section `ACCESS_MASK`. you need really `SECTION_MAP_READ|SECTION_MAP_WRITE` may be `SECTION_QUERY` too